# How to disable the jquery validator 1.13.1 to create new html for error message and use the existing one

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working with jQuery Validator 1.13.1 and I have recently upgraded from JQuery Validator 1.9.0. Now the issue is I was using predefined html for displaying my error messages instead of making jquery validator to create a new html for error message for example:

Using jQuery Validator 1.9.0

```
<span for='first_name' class='error' generated='true'></span>
jQuery(".form-cls").validate({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "error",
       ,
```

and it was working fine.

and now in jQuery Validator 1.13.0

```
<span id="first_name-error" class="error"></span>
jQuery(".form-cls").validate({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "error",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element[0])
            {
                jQuery('#'+element[0].id+'-error').replaceWith(error);
            }
```

Now the jquery validator is using the existing error  to display error as well as it creates a new one. Kindly suggest me how can I disable jquery validator to create a new  for error message and use the existing one. I dont want to use errorPlacement thing :(
        },

Comment: Show a ***more complete*** working example.  **Show the rest of the `.validate()` method and the relevant HTML**.

Comment: Stop trying to write the HTML for the error messages and let the plugin do this automatically, as it was designed.  If you show your example layout and explain where you want the messages inserted, I can provide you with a working solution.